# Magento access Admin Custom Controller without Login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, ce-1.9.2.4

**I tried to access the Admin Controller without Login, it redirects me to Admin login page**. I added below function in my custom controller, but it is not working.

```
public function preDispatch()
    {
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setParam('forwarded', true );
        return parent::preDispatch();
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest, how to make it work.

I tried to rewrite it is not working,

```
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php";

class Namespace_Modulename_Adminhtml_SchooladminController extends Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*');
            return;
        }

        $loginData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('login');
        $username = (is_array($loginData) && array_key_exists('username', $loginData)) ? $loginData['username'] : null;
        echo 'Override';
        exit;
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: login is mandatory to access admin panel. why you want this ? use front controller instead

Comment: I want to use my custom module controller for admin Login page, so url will be my custom controller

Comment: you mean to overwrite login page ?

Comment: yes correct Minesh

Comment: try to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: I tried override controller but not working,  This the requested url which is not working axemusic.local.com/admin/schooladmin/index, I have updated the code in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43337/discussion-between-nagamani-and-minesh-patel).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make your custom admin controller public (i.e. without requiring login, using cookies, etc.), just add this part of code into your controller class:

```
protected function _rewrite() {
    return true;
}
```

Or you can override the preDispatch() method instead (copy as much stuff as you need from all parents and don't call parent in your method).